# Call Mathematica function From .NET

Tags: .netlink

What is the easiest way to call a function defined in *Mathematica* from .NET?  I have the following defined in my current local *Mathematica* session.

```
t = "test";
f[] := (
   str = OpenWrite["C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\test.txt"];
   WriteString[str, t];
   Close[str]);
```

Now I would like to call such a function from .NET. For sake of simplicity I have modified the code slightly from an onchange function into just a main function.

```
using System;
using Wolfram.NETLink;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class File{
 [STAThread]
 // public int Callback(){
 public static void Main(String[] args) {
    MathKernel k = new MathKernel();
    // Doesn't work because separate kernels, I also tried $FrontEnd variables
    k.Compute("f[]");
    //k.Compute("WriteString[str, \"test\"];");
    //k.Compute("Close[str];");
  }
}
```

Is the best solution really to try and implement the code in *Mathematica* form?  The simplest solution at first seemed to involve using `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {TaggingRules, "KernelA"}]` but they don't seem to work when you start kernels from .NET.

Comment: When you say this doesn't work what precisely happens?  Does your code throw an exception? Does a MathKernel process start on your machine or not?

Comment: @Ymareth well the MathKernel starts but I can't call the function because it is in a completely separate kernel.

Comment: Put your definition of f into a file called init.m.  Then call k.Compute("Get[\"init.m\"];");  before calling k.Compute("f[]");  There is a way to get the kernel launched by NETLink to read a specific init.m automatically but I forget how.

Comment: @Ymareth I'm trying to trigger a function that is currently locally running in the FrontEnd of M based on an onchange function in .NET.  Creating a file and calling the file will unfortunately not the direct issue I'm trying to solve.  It would partially work in this example(but not for my intended solution).

Comment: Why do you specifically want to call a function you've defined in the frontend?  Trying to connect a .NET process to an already running kernel that is deep in conversation with the frontend will be tricky but I don't get why you want to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17555/discussion-between-liam-william-and-ymareth).

Comment: Have to be after work :)